# Zero Cost High-Level Snares

Tags: pathfinder-2e, archetype, traps

I am currently building a kobold alchemist with the Snarecrafter archetype. I’ll be taking the Snare Setter ancestry feat at level 1 which in turn grants the Snare Crafting feat. Snare Crafting reads as follows:

> You can use the Craft activity to create snares. When you select this feat, you add the formulas for four common snares to your formula book.

RAW, the feat specifies the rarity **but not** the level of the snares. This seems fine because higher level common snares are prohibitively expensive for a first level character.

However, with the free archetype variant, my kobold could take a Snarecrafter dedication at level 2 which states:

> You've learned to create a limited number of snares at no cost. Each day during your daily preparations, you can prepare four snares from your formula book for quick deployment; if they normally take 1 minute to Craft, you can Craft them with 3 Interact actions. The number of snares increases to six if you're a master in Crafting and eight if you're legendary. Snares prepared in this way don't cost you any resources to Craft.

In this scenario, what’s stopping me from taking multiple level 20 common snares like Flying Blade Wheel Snare and Instant Evisceration Snare at level 1 and crafting them for free from level 2 onwards?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### You Can't Craft Beyond Your Level

> To [Craft](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=43) an item, you must meet the following requirements:
>
> - **The item is your level or lower**. An item that doesn't list a level is level 0. If the item is 9th level or higher, you must be a master in Crafting, and if it's 16th or higher, you must be legendary.
> - ....

There is nothing stopping you from getting some free high-level formulas in your book as you've noticed, though they will be of limited value unless you are similarly leveled or choose to [sell them](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=250). Reasonable GMs probably won't allow selling them to throw the party's wealth out of balance, as 7000 gp at level 2 would be a bit much.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the info I was missing. I think I'll add some level 2 snares to my repertoire when creating the character, but now I know why I shouldn't/wouldn't grab higher level snares.